# rerun logic when an exception is raised in python

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to implement a rerun logic when exception occurs in python

---------rerun.py---------

```
from test import TEST
my_test=TEST(parser.parse_args())
rerun=0
try:
    my_test.main()
except Exception as e:
    print "caught here"
    rerun=rerun+1
    if rerun<3:
        my_test.main()
```

main() calls other methods and I raise an exception in one of those methods.

EX:
----test.py---

```
   def some_method(self):
        raise Exception("testing")

   def main(self):

        self.some_method()
```

When the exception is raised for the first time the rerun works but then in the next run it doesn't return the exception to the rerun.py. rather exits by thorwing the raised exception

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this generic-retry-function a go:

```
def run_with_retries(func, num_retries, exception_types=(Exception,)):
    for i in range(num_retries):
        try:
            # call the function
            return func()
        except exception_types, e:
            # failed on the known exception
            if i == num_retries - 1:
                # this was the last attempt. reraise
                raise
            # retry ...
    assert 0  # should not reach this point
```

In your case, call it like:

```
run_with_retries(my_test.main, 3)
```